# Count verifications in unit test using Fluent Assertions and Nunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, fluent-assertions

I am looking for a solid way to keep track of the number of assertions made in a unit test for reporting purposes in automation. I know that with Nunit one is able to keep track of the assertions that are being made for a test with `TestContext.CurrentContext.AssertCount`. The problem is that my team has our own set of assertion methods using fluent assertions and am looking to find a way to increment that value anytime one is made. Below is a stripped version of one of our unit tests so that you can get an idea of how they read.

```
    [Test]
    public void ServiceHistoryButton_Asset(Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        Threaded<Session>.CurrentBlock<HomePage>()
            ...
            .VerifyThat(form => form.Containerservice.Should().Contain(data["Containerservice"]))
            .VerifyThat(form => form.Account.IsDisplayed().Should().BeTrue())
            .VerifyThat(form => form.ContainerGroup.IsDisplayed().Should().BeTrue())
            .StoreValue<AssetServiceHistoryEdit, DateTime>(form => form.Service.First().ServiceDate, out DateTime firstDate)
            .VerifyThat(form => form.Service.ElementAt(2).ServiceDate.Should().BeBefore(firstDate))
    }
```

I looked into the NUnit framework a bit and if I'm seeing it correctly it looks like they are extending the Assert.That method and adding an incrementer to keep track of when it is called. I thought about doing something similar, but it doesn't look like I can access the `TestContext` outside of the test itself, nor the setup or teardown methods. Let me know if I'm not explaining myself clearly or if I can provide anymore info. Thanks.

Comment: What does `VerifyThat` do? If it calls `Assert.That` or any other assert, then an increment of the count will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no real hook or extension point that you can use for that. All assertions go through the *current* `AssertionScope`. You can wrap all calls in [another scope](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/master/Tests/Shared.Specs/AssertionScopeSpecs.cs#L85), but you have no way to provide an alternative implementation of `IAssertionStrategy`. You could provide me with a PR to make that possible though.